# Plotting two or more ecdfs in R using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

everyone. I`m reading two numeric vectors from files, and I want to plot two ecdfs on the one plot using ggplot2, but I seem to fail:

```
>exp = rnorm(100)
>cont = rnorm(100)
> ggplot() + stat_ecdf(data = exp) + stat_ecdf(data = cont)
Error: ggplot2 doesn't know how to deal with data of class numeric
```

How do I plot them together without getting this kind of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
var1 = rnorm(100)
var2 = rnorm(100)
DF <- data.frame(variable=rep(c('var1', 'var2'), each=100), value=c(var1, var2))
ggplot(DF) + stat_ecdf(aes(value, color=variable))
```

You get an error because you are not using a `data.frame`, which should be a foundamental practice in `ggplot2`. Moreover, you are missing the `aes` which is mandatory when you are dealing with variables. Lastly, try to use `stat_ecdf` only once, and use `color`, `shape`, etc.. to distinguish among different variables.

Comment: @user3570029 If this answer helped you please consider accepting it.